# How to send data in my href = "Home/CompletedGrid?value = ?????"

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-2

**My View**

```
...header content....
@{
var altRow = false;
    foreach (var item in Model.fNameList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td style ="background-color:@(altRow ? "#fff" : "#E0EBEB"); height:40px;width:100px; padding-left:20px;"><a href ="#" onclick='call("@item.techNo");' style ="text-decoration:none; text-decoration-color:black;"> @item.techNo</a></td>
            <td style ="background-color:@(altRow ? "#fff" : "#E0EBEB"); height:40px;width:200px; padding-left:20px;"> @item.firstName @item.lastName</td>
        </tr> 
        altRow = !altRow;
    }                                                   
}
...content...
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.techNo, new { @class="form-control maintain-text", placeholder="Technician No..."})
...content...
<a id="completed"class="btn btn-default" target="_blank" href="Home/CompletedGrid?value=@*m.techNo*@"><i class='fa fa-check fa-fw'></i>Completed</a>
```

I want to send my *m.techNo* value to my **"Home/CompletedGrid?value=//m.techNo//"** but when I try it didn't work, even its *@Model.techNo* the value is still NULL. How can I send my value techNo to my **Home/CompletedGrid?value=@*m.techNo*@**, Do I need to change my razor or should I add something in my script.

**My script**

```
function call(x) { $("#techNo").val(x); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just need to transfer the **target="_blank" href="Home/CompletedGrid?value=@*m.techNo*@"** to my script function **call("@item.techNo")**

**script**

```
function call(x) 
{
    $("#techNo").val(x); 
    $("#completed").attr("href", "Home/CompletedGrid?value=" + x);
            $("#completed").attr("target", "_blank");
}
```

and it works perfectly...